# How to set UA and Headless for Selenium of Safari?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, safari

#### Ideal

I'd like to set User Agent and Headless for Selenium of Safari, just like ChromeOptions.
The reason I choose Safari is that I need to capture the website which is available only for Safari.

#### What I have tried

I searched but found few informations.
Then, I wrote the code below like SafariOption (mimic like ChromeOption), but it failed.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = webdriver.SafariOptions()
options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1')

browser = webdriver.Safari(options, executable_path = '/usr/bin/safaridriver')
browser.get('http://google.com')
time.sleep(10)
browser.quit()
```

Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running headless is not possible right now with the safari driver -https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5985

Here are all the user agents for safari - https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/safari/